# Textbooks used by Oliver Heaviside

Tags: mathematicians, biographical-details, heaviside

Oliver Heaviside achieved a very high level in mathematics and physics by self-study, starting from a modest school-level math, and working alone in his room, without a tutor. Is it known what textbooks he used?

Comment: You may want to read [this article](https://doi.org/10.1063/PT.3.1788).

Comment: Some of the text books he used would have of been written by James Clerk Maxwell. I know he was a relation (nephew?) of Charles Wheatstone so literature written by Charles Wheatstone might be a port of call.